# Simple form date_field not populating for edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using rails 4 simple form to store some data. My date field stores fine, but the form input is mm-dd-yyyy and stores with yyyy-mm-dd.

When I do an edit action on the form, everything returns except for the date, which doesn't fill in.

**view**

```
<div class="input-group">
 <%= f.date_field :date_requested, as: :date%>
</div>
```

**model**

```
attribute :date_requested, :datetime
```

[image: date field]

[image]

Comment: Required code of your model and controller to investigate problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the format of data stored in the database and the format of the date you are showing on view. Database stores date in yyyy/mm/dd and it seems like on view you want to show in mm/dd/yyyy format

```
<%= f.date_field :date_requested, as: :date, value: f.object.date_requested.try(:strftime,"%m/%d/%Y") %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @shweta, this gives the following error.
    undefined method `date_requested' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fee89321d90>

Comment: Updated my answer. f is object of formbuilder we need to convert it into object of model (Activerecord) using object method.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just doing `<%= f.date_field :date_requested, as: :date, value: f.object.date_requested %>` That seems to work on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the default time format.

In your /config/initializers directory create a ruby file, named so you recognize what it is -- I use time_formats.rb, and add a line for each of the time date formats you will want to use. For example, for the commonly used Month Day, Year:

time_formats.rb

```
# Setup date view format
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_day_and_year] = "%b %d, %Y"
```

Then in your view you pass the time data database value formatted via your initialize.

```
(Edited <%= yourmodelinstance.your_date_field.to_s(:month_day_and_year) %>.)
```

Will show "(Edited Mar 01, 2015)"

The database time field format is not at play at all. You have to create the filter to translate the raw time/date data into string form.

It is possible to define the way you display the date very specifically. For all possible formats, please see the Ruby docs here => http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

One more important thing: You can use the helper formatter anywhere you use the date field, on a form, view, etc.